# Min-max normalization: rescaling twice for a specific goal in an index

Tags: normalization

I'm constructing an index using an individual indicator that I will call **M** and it goes from 0 to 10.

The index is normalized using Rescaling, therefore it goes from 0 to 1. However, I'm dividing it into two groups for better interpretation: 0-0.7 means a developing territory, whereas 0.7-1 means developed. The reason for that is that this is the best grouping considering other several individual indicators.

Also, I have an official goal (set by researchers) for this individual indicator **M**: scoring 6 out of 10 is good enough to be considered developed.

The thing is, if I use Rescaling (x-min)/(max-min), scoring 6 out of 10 would get a normalized score of 0.6, which would mean "developing", when it should've been placed in the developed group, scoring 0.7.

I've tried the following:

**M = [x - min(x)] / [max(x) - min(x)] * 0.7** for scores less than or equal to 6.

where **M** is the individual indicator, **x** is the score from 0 to 6, **min** is the minimum value (0), and **max** is the goal (6 out of 10)

and

**M = {[x - min(x)] / [max(x) - min(x)] * 0.3} +0.7** for scores equal or greater than 6.

where **M** is the individual indicator, **x** is the score from 6 to 10, **min** is the goal (6), and **max** is the maximum value (10)

which resolved the matter by Rescaling twice: one for values from 0 to 0.7, and another rescaling for values from 0.7 to 1. My question is: is it an appropriate way to solve this problem?

I've never seen this approach, which makes me think it might not have the approval among composite indicator specialists.